# Average of differences over Counted / Summed Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have shipment data between origins and destinations over a 52 week period. I'm trying to
a) find the number of shipments between an origin and destination for each week 1 - 52
b) Find differences in no. of shipments between each week (week 2 - wk 1, week 3 - wk 2, etc...)
c) Find the average of those differences for each OD Pair.

```
SELECT
   [Origin],
   [Destination],
   AVG(ABS(SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END)-SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 1 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END)) + ABS(SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END)-SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END)) + ABS(SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 4 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END)-SUM(CASE 
      WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END))
```

for 52 weeks.

But it returns

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just divide the sum by 3?

```
SELECT [Origin], [Destination], 
       (ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
        ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
        ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
       ) / 3
```

Comment: That's embarrassingly obvious. Thank you